# Google Analytics with java not working on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

Hello all java/google/linux experts :)

So..I've created a java program that extracts data from Google analytics and creates a small csv file. I have tested the program on my local machine (windows 7) however when i try to upload the program to a linux server it does not work. I have changed all the necessary directories so that it will work with linux.

When I go to run the program on the Linux server, it prompts me to go to a google website to authenticate my login....after I do, i get 3 randomly generated numbers as a result in putty

For example:
17956
17957
17958

Anyone have any idea what the error is? or even point me in the right direction....kind of clueless on what is happening here

Thanks all

EDIT: still have not figured out the issue....anyone?

Comment: If it doesn't work, I presume that you're getting some kind of exception or error message.  Do you have that?  Are you sure that the Linux machine is configured in a similar manner as the Windows machine?

Comment: Hmmm I am not getting an error message i am just getting these sequential 3 numbers. I have no idea what these numbers mean

Comment: sounds like you are having a problem with authentication.  Are you using Oauth2 or a service account?  If Oauth2 native application or??

Comment: Yes i am using Oauth2 and selecting the native appilcation option am i missing a step here?